# In which order are MySQL left join conditions evaluated?

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I'm having the following query:

```
SELECT
*
FROM ARTICLE AS article

LEFT JOIN VALUATION AS valuation ON (valuation.ARTICLEID = article.ID  AND valuation.BUYDATE <= '2021-10-21'
AND   valuation.SELLDATE > '2021-10-21' )
LEFT JOIN VALUATION AS previousvaluation ON(previousvaluation.ARTICLEID = article.ID AND  
AND  previousvaluation.BUYDATE < '2021-10-21' AND   previousvaluation.SELLDATE >= '2021-10-21' AND article.NOTICEDATE < '2021-10-21')
LEFT JOIN ART_OWNER AS articleOwner ON (articleOwner.ID = article.owner )

WHERE article.QUANTITY = 0
```

It is giving me the following execution plan:

[image]

As seen in the execution plan,the "previousValuation" lookup is showing 10 rows produced which multiply data processed by the "articleOwner" join by 10.
My "previousValuation" join will ALWAYS return 0 or 1 line but it is showing 10 rows just because the join is not a ref join and is only taking usage of one column in the table PK.
Why this join is not taking in consideration non indexed columns and is join condition on those non indexed columns evaluated at the join time or later?

(When is the "attached_condition" condition evaluated)
Thanks

Comment: This is an execution *plan*. MySQL guesses/plans with 10 rows there, but has no obvious way of knowing that there is only one row (after applying all conditions) without reading the actual data first. If the plan is slow and/or you think (or want us to check if) there is a better plan, please provide details about your indexes.

Comment: (I see `AND AND`; I hope there are no other typos.)

Answer (score 0):

These might help:

```
VALUATION:  INDEX(ARTICLEID, SELLDATE)
VALUATION:  INDEX(ARTICLEID, BUYDATE)
```

And drop `INDEX(ARTICLEID)` if you have such.  (The single-column version may get in the way of my suggested pair of indexes.)

The numbers in Explain are estimates -- sometimes very crude estimates.  They are sometimes very far off and can lead to using the wrong query plan.

The order of `LEFT JOINs` should not matter.  The number of rows fetched (or found to be missing) does not change depending on the order.

When there are two ranges in `ON` (or `WHERE`), the Optimizer will use only one of them.  My suggestion should help the Optimizer try both directions (past and future) in hopes that it will discover (via probes into the index) which one will be more productive.

`LEFT` is often used when it should not be.  Are you sure you need it in these cases?

Do you really want `SELECT *`?  It provides all columns from all 4 tables.

> Why this join is not taking in consideration non indexed columns and is join condition on those non indexed columns evaluated at the join time or later?

(I'm unclear on what you are asking.)  The evaluation happens in (crudely) this order:

1. Filter by `INDEX` (if appropriate)
2. Fetch the entire row for any rows that have not been filtered out by the `INDEX`
3. Perform the "attached condition" to finish the filtering.

That's all.  The second step gathered all the data; there is no step 4 to optimize.  I could be wrong here.  If there are columns that are stored "off-record" (eg big `TEXT` or `BLOB`), they may not have been fetched in step 2.  (I do not know the answer to this.)

(And that hints at a big reason for not saying `SELECT *` if you have big columns that you do not need to fetch.)